# android app Frozen after updating latest gradle

Tags: android

After updating latest android gradle 7.1.2 and compileSdkVersion 32 app Frozen like in the picture

```
 android {
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bad.good"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 33
    versionName "4.3"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it. one of the old library Couse this app Frozen. After removing that library it fixed ..

Comment: happy you found it but this is not a good quality answer, put the library name. Did you replace it with a newer version or did not need it? please see the [qna] or some of the other high score answers. Maybe you just need to add a comment to your question or delete it. as your question does not list the libraries ...